Keypad not recognised 2-in-1 (touchscreen laptop)
I recently installed ubuntu 24.04 for the first time on a new laptop, iota 360. Its what they call 2 in 1. I set it up using the mouse and the touch screen also functioned. Now when I log in, only the touch screen is recognised and the keypad doesn't move the mouse. How can I change this?
Thanks
